# I messed up systemd-boot by being foolish. No longer able to boot into PopOS or windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub, systemd-boot

I did the classic thing of being in a rush and not thinking, copying the following commands blindly from [this other post](https://old.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/9q3u3a/dual_boot_issue_need_help_how_to_setup/e86mzwj/).

```
sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64 
sudo bootctl remove 
sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootl
```

I'll also add that installed [dark matter grub theme](https://github.com/vandalsoul/darkmatter-grub2-theme), not sure if that's relevant but that's the order in which things happened. Followed by a reboot and the following images.

When I rebooted I was met with [this grub terminal](https://i.imgur.com/qCC9Q1L.png), where I've no idea to even start.

I went to my UEFI BIOS to check that perhaps I just needed to change the boot priority to see [that my windows drive has disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrE2m.jpg). I have my pop os installed on a 500gb drive and my windows install on a 120gb drive. But the BIOS is seeing two 500gb drives and no 128gb drive.

I'm pretty pissed at myself for being so lazy and not thinking straight. I'm assuming that the computer is going to look for these EFI files that point to the correct bootloaders or something along those lines but effectively I've gone and deleted them.

---

Since then I've booted from a live USB, installed rEFInd, and ran `sudo bootctl install` which has given me back my recovery boot at least so I no longer need my USB, which I guess is something.

Seems to be that I either end up in the grub terminal or a initramfs terminal.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this?

---

EDIT: Here is a bootinfo report http://sprunge.us/rZsOCu

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the help. I booted up on my live USB and generated the following report. Hopefully that helps http://sprunge.us/rZsOCu

Comment: What are sdb, sdc & sdd? Are those really encrypted LVM as you show a swap entry in fstab using /dev/mapper/cryptswap. It does not look like rEFInd is configurated for anything. Grub looks like it should work as GUID/partUUID all seem to match. Not sure about systemD boot, as I do not know it.

Comment: sdb, sdc and sdd are my 3 hard drives in a raid 0 array where I just store video games for Windows. Nothing on my system should be encrypted. As popOS doesn't use grub and I forgot that detail, introducing grub seems to have meet up systemd-boot which is what is used instead of grub.

Comment: Boot-Repair cannot help on a systemD boot. Boot-Repair's normal fix is a grub menu update or full reinstall of grub.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like it's not much of an answer as it doesn't fix the problem directly but for completion here's how it's now all sorted.

Firstly, I did a fresh install of Pop_OS. That removed the grub problems and created that OS bootable.

Secondly, with windows, I created a usb for that so I could boot into. Then went into the advanced repair for the terminal and used `diskpart` to look at the situation. Initially no drives were showing up at all other than the usb that I was running off. I forgot that this was an issue due to my raid array being done via the motherboard and you have to load some drivers in to see all the drives. Following [the directions for that](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/TUF_GAMING_X570-PLUS_WI-FI/E14794_RAID_Configuration_Guide_EM_V4_WEB.pdf) which is obviously motherboard specific; I was able to view the drives in diskpart. I listed the disks, selected the one that looked like the right size, selected the volume that seemed appropriate, renamed the drive letter, and ran the command `bcdboot C:\windows /s V: /f UEFI` with the appropriate drive letters, which took some looking around.

After all that my Windows drive was recognised and I could boot into it and it was also appearing on my boot menu.